# Problem with SUM on Matrix blocks

Tags: matrix, query

I have some Matrix blocks where I need to sum one of the fields within, but I only want to sum it when another field within that block is or is not empty.

```twig
{% set reimbursementAmount = craft.matrixBlocks()
  .relatedTo(cat)
  .fieldId(9)
  .sum('field_item_reimbursementAmount')
  .specialCase(':empty:')
  %}
```

With this, I get an error:

**Impossible to invoke a method ("specialCase") on a string variable ("101.00").**

How do I sum the desired field, but only where another field (specialCase) is empty (or is not empty, as the case may be).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but I think `.sum()` will execute your query, so put it at the end:

```
{% set reimbursementAmount = craft.matrixBlocks()
  .relatedTo(cat)
  .fieldId(9)
  .specialCase(':empty:')
  .sum('field_item_reimbursementAmount')
%}
```

Comment: Thanks, ended up using a Twig loop to SUM the values.